# Activity not found exception with twitter

Tags: android, exception

I have the following code to tweet something from my app:

```
try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Blah blah blah");
            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final List<?> activityList = pm
                    .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            int len = activityList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                final ResolveInfo app = (ResolveInfo) activityList.get(i);
                if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity"
                        .equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android",
                            "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");

                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            onCreateDialog(NO_APP);
        }

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {

    case NO_APP: {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_small);
        builder.setTitle("Twitter");
        builder.setMessage("No Twitter app found");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });

        dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
    default:
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
}
```

If twitter is installed on my phone, then the app works fine and a new tweet is generated. If the app does not exist, I want a dialog to appear stating that there is no app. However, as of now nothing happens when there is no twitter app in the phone. When I press the tweet button on my app, nothing happens. What do I need to do to make the dialog appear in this case?

Comment: You want to exec the official twitter app from your app? Are you aware that exists the official api to twit something regardless you have the app or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exception if the twitter Application is not found.
Change you code to:

```
try {
boolean found = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Blah blah blah");
            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final List<?> activityList = pm
                    .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            int len = activityList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                final ResolveInfo app = (ResolveInfo) activityList.get(i);
                if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity"
                        .equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
found = true;
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android",
                            "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");

                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
            }
if(!found)  onCreateDialog(NO_APP);
        } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            onCreateDialog(NO_APP);
        }
```

Or Try to start the twitter application and handle the not found exception.

```
try {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
            startActivity(intent);

        } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            onCreateDialog(NO_APP);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!! that worked . But why was there no exception when twitter was not found?

Comment: Because the ActivityNotFoundException is fired when you try to start an activity, or within you code if the twitter activity is not found you are not starting the twitter intent. I will edit the Answer to show you how to handle the exception.
PS: if the answer was useful accept it ;)